# Insert map into vector fails second time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, vector, dictionary

I have an error I couldn't figure where it occues on the following:

I'm acutally using a map with vectors in it:
`map<vector<string> , vector<string> > parameterMap;`

because I need a few of them (how many is decided on runtime) I put them into a list (vector):
vector declaration on head of method:
`vector<map<vector<string> , vector<string> > > listedParameterMap;`

insertion of a map into the vector:
`listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), 1, parameterMap);`

This procedure works fine on the first time. The second time (map is filled correctly) it down't work.
I noticed a thing: I give out the size of the map:
`cout << "listedParameterMap " << listedParameterMap.size();`
it shown **size** is **2** after the second time, the **watch** says it still **1**.
It also shows me wired content:

Screenshot:
[image]

`Last` should contain something looking like `First`
The second map which is inserted is defently filled correctly.
Same for the vectors: `part1_input` and `part2_output`

**Code:**

```
for (unsigned int index = 0; index < part1_input.size(); index++) {
        map<vector<string> , vector<string> > parameterMap;
        parameterMap.insert
        (pair<vector<string> , vector<string> > (part1_input[index], part2_output[index]));
        listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), 1, parameterMap);
        cout << "listedParameterMap " << listedParameterMap.size();
}
```

I really would appreciate any ideas why this happens...

---

---

**EDIT:**

"Solution" was printing the stuff out. The watch-window isn't displaying the correct values. That means my Problem is caused somewhere else. But this here is anwsered. Thanks to anyone how tried to help me!

Comment: Please define "it don't work".

Comment: Also, please consider using typedefs!

Comment: Look at the picture... giving me -1 before asking isn't helping me!
You can see there the second entry (`Last`) it's not like it should be (similiar to `First`)

Comment: We need to know what error you're getting, and what's the "wired content"? And does the compiler throw an error, or is it just a runtime error?

Comment: Don't you see the screenshot I inserted?

Comment: @Beasly - your screenshot is blocked at work. Perhaps others are missing it for the same reason. Could you add a description of the screenshot please.

Comment: sure! fist item is normal like: `_Myfirst>[0]>first(content on next column)>second(same)`  
The second item which fails: `_Mylast>(error)>(error)>(error)>(error)>(error) lots of times`  
Does it help it I upload the pic somewhere else?  
because I don't know how to explain better... :/

Comment: A `map` with a `vector` *as the key*?  This has got to be one of the oddest things I've ever seen.  Almost certainly the Wrong Thing.

Comment: Yes, my intention is to match both sides. Key has always same size as value. It was working before already but only 2 dimensional... now i'm trying to get it working in 3 dimensions because of changed requirements. As I said a map containing vectors for key and value was working before. The differnce now, it's a list of such maps. Filling this list is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to see a test where you output something from your collections to see if you are seeing what you think you should see. Actually why not write a proper unit test?

You are passing a lot of collections around by value. This can be quite expensive, but in addition, you may be updating something that is a copy of what you think you are actually updating, and then not seeing the results in the original.

I would not pay too much attention to values in Visual Studio's "watch" window, particularly if you are running an optimised build.

Comment: it seems to be in correctly. I don't understand then why the program crashes on using this **list**. I thought because it's not filled correctly (watches). I'll keep looking. If I don't find it I'll open a new question. Thank you!